# Taxonomy Terms jump list

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I have created a jump list with certain taxonomy terms, but it seems impossible to get the url right.

I have a URL pattern setup for these terms: /dealers/towns/[taxonomy_term]

But in the jump list I can't find a way to get this url right, there's no way to select the actual url, how can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a new field on the view, which is custom link.
edit this custom link and rewrite the result to be something like

```
<a href="/dealers/towns/[taxonomy_term]">term</a>
```

after that click on your jump list settings and chose the newly created field